# Stream a string into pygments lexer?

Tags: python, json, streaming, syntax-highlighting, pygments

I'd like to use pygments to highlight code for me on the fly - basically a huge list of JSON objects. Here's what I tried:

```
from pygments.lexers import JsonLexer
from pygments.formatters import HtmlFormatter
from pygments import highlight
import StringIO
f = StringIO.StringIO()
f.write('a')
f.seek(0)
print highlight(f, JsonLexer(), HtmlFormatter())
```

This gave me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/d33tah/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygments/__init__.py", line 87, in highlight
    return format(lex(code, lexer), formatter, outfile)
  File "/home/d33tah/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygments/__init__.py", line 45, in lex
    return lexer.get_tokens(code)
  File "/home/d33tah/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygments/lexer.py", line 151, in get_tokens
    text, _ = guess_decode(text)
  File "/home/d33tah/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygments/util.py", line 309, in guess_decode
    text = text.decode('utf-8')
AttributeError: StringIO instance has no attribute 'decode'
```

Clearly this is wrong interface. What would be the right one?

Answer (score 0):

highlight expects f to be a string, which has a decode attribute. StringIO doesn't have that attribute.

```
In [30]: type(f)
Out[30]: instance

In [31]: type(f.read())
Out[31]: str
```

Just use a straight string.

```
In [34]: pygments.highlight('a', lexer, formatter)
Out[34]: u'<div class="highlight"><pre><span></span><span class="err">a</span>\n</pre></div>\n'
```